# Sending logs from local to aws s3 using telegraf

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, telegraf

I'm facing issue and got error:

```
2024-02-27T12:37:47Z I! Loading config: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2024-02-27T12:37:47Z E! error loading config file /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf: error parsing s3 array, undefined but requested output: s3
2024-02-27T12:39:23Z I! Loading config: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2024-02-27T12:39:23Z E! error loading config file /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf: error parsing s3 array, undefined but requested output: s3
```

I am running this in the container.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You did read the error right? It says there's a parsing the config.

Answer (score 0):

There is no s3 output in the official builds of Telegraf as of this message. The error message is letting you know that the output is undefined in the version of telegraf you are running.